# CCNET is not run correctly

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have installed the ccnet 1.6.798 on Windows 7 Ent.
After fews time is run correctly, now its just load some line and then go to hang .
Nothing happen anymore,
Can somebody help me to solve this matter,
I have this problem on windows server 2k8 too.

```
   [CCnet Server:INFO] Starting Cruisecontrol.Net Server
  [CCnet Server:INFO] Initialising security
```

Here is screenshot:

```
    http://postimg.org/image/irgl0kbpd/
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not hang. As you can see in the debug log you have not configured any projects. So there is nothing todo for CCNet.

Please read the [documentation](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Configuration) about how to add projects to your configuration.

Also the [Scenarios](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Scenarios) are a very helpful source to get startet.